# How to create tier price amount according to value

Tags: php, excel, numbers

I'm setting up a webshop to use in a printshop but I'm stuck on how to automatically provide prices for different amounts.

In example:

The client wants to see the price for 100 sheets and immediately it should see the price for 150, 200, 250, ... (it's cheaper per piece every time you the amount is larger).

This is easy of course; get `$amount` and add +50 every time. But when the client asks 1000 it should not be +50 but maybe +100.

Is there a slick and easy way to do this or is it going to be a lot of

`if($amount < 100){ add +50 }elseif($amount > 100 && < 500){ add + 75 }`....?

Comment: suggest u to create a function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about this:

```
  $amount = 100; // client's amount
  $i = 1; // iterator
  $suggested = array(); // array for suggested amounts
  $increment = ($amount / 2); // half of client's suggested amount
  # while loop
  while ($i <= 3) {
    $amount = $amount + $increment; // formula
    array_push($suggested, $amount); // add to array
    $i++;
  }
  # will output 150, 200, 250
  foreach ($suggested as $s) {
    echo $s . '<br />';
  }
```

Will that get you started in the right direction?